# How can I aggregate unique occurrences by year?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of this format

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1980 4
1980 4
1980 7
1980 32
1981 3
1981 3
1981 3
1981 3
1981 9
1992 10
1992 11
```

And I would like to have a dataframe of this nature:

```
col1 col2
1980 3
1981 2
1992 2
```

Basically, to count the number of ***unique*** occurrences of col2 every year. The dataframe contains lots of other columns (col3,col4 etc), but not a part of this analysis. I have previously used table to summarize for a single column, but don't know how to do this.

Comment: try `table(unique(df)$year)`   (assuming your data.frame is called 'df', and your year column is called 'year')

Comment: @tospig Thanks. I have added some more information. I need to aggregate based on only col2. Hope I am able to explain properly.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I can simply subset...

Comment: Yes, a combindation of subsetting `[`, `unique` and `table` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aggregate(col2~col1,df,function(x)length(unique(x)))

or 
library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(col1)%>%summarize(count=length(unique(col2)))
```

Comment: Youshouldinvestinakeyboardwithaspacebar